# C++ Reading fixed number of lines of integers with unknown number of integers in each line

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I'm trying to read in data and solve simple problem, data :

```
3               - number of lines to read in
1 1
2 2 2
3 4
```

after each line is entered I would like to obtain sum of entered numers, but number of integers in each line is unknown. After using above data screen should look like this :

```
3               
1 1
Sum: 2
2 2 2
Sum: 6
3 4 
Sum: 7
```

But from my algorithm I've got the output :

```
3
1 1
Sum: 1
2 2 2
Sum: 4
3 4
Sum: 3
```

I've written code, but it doesn't work properly (as above):
**EDITION**
**I improved my code and know it works properly without strings etc., proper code is below :**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x;
    int t, sum;
    cin >> t;

    for(int i=0; i<t; i++) {
        sum=0;
        while(true)
        {
            cin >> x;
            sum = sum + x;  
            if(cin.peek()=='\n')
                break; //conditional break
        }
        cout << "Sum: " << sum << "\n";
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Did you tried to figure out with debugger why it does not work?

Comment: "doesn't work" means exactly what?

Comment: there is no message from compiler I've get the output

Comment: t is an undefined value

Comment: @ QuentinUK isn't  `int t;` enought ?

Comment: Now try typing in a line of numbers that ends with a *space* before the `enter` key.

Comment: @Pete Becker yes I know :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read a line at a time, using `getline`, into an object of type `std::string`. Then use that `std::string` object to initialize an object of type `std::istringstream`, and use an extractor to read `int` values from the stream object until it fails. Then go back and read the next line. Roughly:

```
std::string line;
while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
    std::istringstream in(line);
    int sum = 0;
    int value = 0;
    while (in >> value)
        sum += value;
    std::cout << sum << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Or use [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate).

Comment: is there solution without additional stuff (string) ?

Comment: This is idiomatic C++, anything else would be sub-optimal.

Comment: @Peter Wood is my solution sub-optimal ? I've improved it and now it works.

Comment: @Qbik - sure, if you like complicated code. `<g>` It's very common to have to parse line-oriented input, and this approach is simple and effective.

Comment: @Qbik Managing loops is a common source for bugs. You actually have to trace through your code to understand what it's doing. You have a `while(true)` - are you sure that the `break` will happen? What if the last line has no newline? Also, the non-locality of references means it takes time to understand how `sum` and `x` are related.

Answer (score 1):

C++ gives you many tools:

- `string` is a class managing the lifetime of character strings.
- `getline` puts a line from a stream (up to the next newline) into a `string`.
- `istringstream` makes an `istream` out of a `string`
- `istream_iterator` iterates over an `istream`, extracting the given type, breaking on whitespace.
- `accumulate` takes iterators delimiting a range and adds together the values:

Altogether:

```
string line;
while (getline(cin, line)) {
    istringstream in(line);
    istream_iterator<int> begin(in), end;
    int sum = accumulate(begin, end, 0);
    cout << sum << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put

`sum=0;` // at the top

ps

```
while(cin.peek()!='\n'){


}
```

Comment: `cin.peek()!='\n'` yes but compiler on SPOJ usually won't get it so I have to use `while(true)`